# How to envelope web api response conventionally int .netcore api

Tags: c#, .net-core

One of my web api project *-uses .NetCore 2.1-* i want to have a convention of returning messages. All successful result objects must be enveloped with a `result` object and all errors and such things must leave `result` null and fill the `resultCode` and `resultMessage` fields.
Should i do this on `startup.cs` with formatters or create a response builder class and not use `[ApiController]` attribute tag features such as `Ok(), NotFound() etc..` *which i really want to use*.
I could not find any documentation or guideline for this purpose. 
Here is my code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("applicaiton/json")]
public IActionResult GetValues()
{
    var toRet = new[] {"value1", "value2"};
    return Ok(toRet);
}
```

This codeblock returns `["value1","value2"]` but i need it like this

```
{
    "result": ["value1","value2"],
    "resultCode": 200,
    "resultMessage": "OK"
}
```

How and where can i achieve this convention?

> Edit

Excuse my on my example code. I will use custom error codes in my responses. Most probably `200 OK` will be

```
{
    "result" : "some value",
    "resultCode" : 0,
    "resultMessage" : "All values returned"
}
```

And `400 Bad Request` will be

```
{
    "result" : null,
    "resultCode" : 20468,
    "resultMessage" : "Dont have any value to show!"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you defined a new `JsonOutputFormatter` with an overridden `WriteResponseBodyAsync`:

```
public class SuperJsonOutputFormatter:JsonOutputFormatter
{
    public SuperJsonOutputFormatter(
        JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings, 
        ArrayPool<char> charPool) : base(serializerSettings, charPool)
    {
    }
    public override async Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(
        OutputFormatterWriteContext context, 
        Encoding selectedEncoding)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        if (selectedEncoding == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selectedEncoding));
        using (TextWriter writer = 
            context.WriterFactory(
                context.HttpContext.Response.Body, 
                selectedEncoding))
        {
            var rewrittenValue = new
            {
                result = context.Object, 
                resultCode = context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode, 
                resultMessage =
                    ((HttpStatusCode) context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode)
                        .ToString()
            };
            this.WriteObject(writer, rewrittenValue);
            await writer.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

You could de-register the old `JsonOutputFormatter` and replace it with your new-spanky formatter in `Startup.ConfigureServices` as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(opts =>
    {
        var oldFormatter = 
            opts.OutputFormatters.OfType<JsonOutputFormatter>().Single();
        opts.OutputFormatters.Remove(oldFormatter);
        var replacementJsonOutputFormatter = 
            new SuperJsonOutputFormatter(oldFormatter.PublicSerializerSettings,
            ArrayPool<char>.Shared);
        opts.OutputFormatters.Add(replacementJsonOutputFormatter);
    }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

...and keep the code in your controllers exactly the same as before.

Of course, if (for instance) the client only accepts XML, then content-negotiation will skip this formatter. If you only want JSON output, deregister any other output formatters.

Comment: With dependency injection: services.AddSingleton<IOutputFormatter, SuperJsonOutputFormatter>();
            services.AddSingleton(_ => JsonSerializerSettingsProvider.CreateSerializerSettings());

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<JsonOutputFormatter>();

                var formatter = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IOutputFormatter>();
                options.OutputFormatters.Add(formatter);
            })

Answer (score 0):

The status code 200 OK refers to the [HTTP status code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6), which is part of the HTTP protocol. The status code is part of the HTTP header, whereas your result is part of the content.

Since this is part of the HTTP protocol it is universally supported and there is little reason for you to duplicate this information in your message. The other side of the HTTP connection will be able to extract this information from the header. It will also have already an infrastructure to handle the status code, like a web browser that will automatically redirect after a 3xx response and show an error page on a 4xx response.

All this is also true for a REST service like the one you are building. REST is based on HTTP and so there is nothing wrong to use the features of this protocol. So I suggest you think if you *really* need this information in the content.

If you still want this information as part of the message content, you can manually add it yourself:

```
public class ResultMessage<T> {
    public T Result { get; set; }
    public HttpStatusCode ResultCode { get; set; }
    public string ResultMessage { get; set; }
}

ResultMessage<T> GetResultMessage<T>(T value, HttpStatusCode resultCode) {
    return new ResultMessage<T> {
        Result = value,
        ResultCode = resultCode,
        ResultMessage = resultCode.ToString()
    };
}

[HttpGet]
[Produces("application/json")]
public IActionResult GetValues()
{
    var toRet = new[] {"value1", "value2"};
    return Ok(GetResultMessage(toRet, HttpStatusCode.OK));
}
```

Comment: Actually i need to edit my question. I will use custom error codes on `resultCode`. like 20001 for authorization error, 20406 for some business error and so on. My success `resultCode` will be `0` in this case. I meant to envelope a result with an outer format in my question.